# ¿Cómo introducir el símbolo "%" en un archivo Bat?

Tags: batch, línea-de-comandos

estoy creando un programa en código DOS con extensión `".bat"` pero tengo el pequeño problema de que quiero mostrar un porcentaje y para esto necesito imprimir en pantalla el símbolo `"%"`.

He de agregar que ya probé con "%", '%' y *%* pero de ninguna de esas tres formas me funcionó, agradecería la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sino estoy mal, en código DOS se podía imprimir cualquier símbolo con doble porcentaje, es decir `%así%`.

Ya que el doble porcentaje hace llamado a una variable, pero si la variable está vacía, imprime el nombre de esta, por lo cual, si tenemos una variable que se llama "X" y su contenido es "3", al decir `echo %X%` nos imprimirá "3" pero si esta variable estuviera vacía o no estuviera definida, entonces nos imprimirá "X".

Comment: Gracias, lo intenté así y funcionó, además gracias por la explicación

Answer (score 3):

Esta un poco extraño pero requieres usar `%%` para escapar solo ese signo. Para otros mira esta [lista.](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

Comment: Acabo de ver el enlace que compartiste, hay algunas cosas que yo no sabía, así que también voto por tu respuesta.